# Series Induction problem set:

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

For all $n$ belonging to $\mathbb N$, let $A_n$ be the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ that do not contain any two consecutive members (including $\emptyset$);

(a) Show that $A_n$ is the $(n+2)^\text{th}$ Fibonacci Number.

Comment: split up in subsets that contain $n$ and subsets that do not contain $n$. That way you can find a (familiar) relation between $A_n$, $A_{n-1}$ and $A_{n-2}$.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? What is the part that you have problems with? 
(Note: the problem concerns a sequence, not a series- a series is a sum of the terms of a sequence, informally.)

Comment: @drhab can you be more specific? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote set of the subsets of $\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\} $ that do not contain
two consecutive numbers by $\mathcal{A}_{n}$.

Then $A_{n}$ is the
cardinality of $\mathcal{A}_{n}$.

Note that $\mathcal{A}_{n}=\mathcal{A}_{n-1}\cup\left\{ T\cup\left\{ n\right\} \mid T\in\mathcal{A}_{n-2}\right\} $.

These sets are disjoint so that $A_{n}=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$.

Comment: I don't really know about cardinality..can you explain? Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: @OKthen : The cardinality of a set is simply the number of members that it has.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: If we have a set {1,2,3,4,5} with n=5, about its subsets, are they {}, {1,3}, {1,3,5}, {2,4}, {3,5}? If so then a_n = 5, but the fifth Fib number is 3...Can you explain why they are all disjoint?

Comment: If $n=5$ then we have the sets $\emptyset$, $\left\{ 1\right\} $,
$\left\{ 2\right\} $, $\left\{ 3\right\} $, $\left\{ 4\right\} $,
$\left\{ 5\right\} $, $\left\{ 1,3\right\} $, $\left\{ 1,4\right\} $,
$\left\{ 1,5\right\} $, $\left\{ 2,4\right\} $, $\left\{ 2,5\right\} $,
$\left\{ 3,5\right\} $, $\left\{ 1,3,5\right\} $. So $A_{5}=13=F_{7}$.